# Cannot get above 55% TRAINING accuracy on wine quality dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I have tried a logistic regression model as well as just making the NN a little bigger, tried to tune learning rate, excluding some useless features but I still can't get above 0.55 training accuracy. Here's is some of my code:

**Importing files**

```
df_red = pd.read_csv('winequality-red.csv', sep=';')
df_white = pd.read_csv('winequality-white.csv', sep=';')

df = df_red.append(df_white, ignore_index=True)
```

**Excluding outliers**

```
from scipy import stats

df_new = df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df)) < 3).all(axis=1)]
```

**Scaling the data**

```
Y = df_new['quality']

df_new = df_new.drop(['quality'], axis=1)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler = StandardScaler()

df_new = scaler.fit_transform(df_new)

X = df_new[:, 0:11]
Y = Y.reshape(-1, 1)
```

**Splitting the data**

```
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.20)
```

**One-hot encoding**

```
Y_train = to_categorical(Y_train)
print(Y_train[0:7])
Y_test = to_categorical(Y_test)
print(Y_test[0:7])
```

**Model**

```
# Define our model
def model(X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test):
global network_history
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, input_shape=(11,), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(9, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

network_history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=200, shuffle=True, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))

score = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)

print("Test score ", score[0])
print("Test accuracy ", score[1])

return model
```

What can I do to improve this?

Comment: How many training samples you have? What is the initial value of accuracy? Does the loss decrease very slowly during training? And what is the validation accuracy?

Comment: I have 4791 training samples out of 5989. Initial value of accuracy was 0.1945. Loss decreases very slowly. Validation accuracy was also in the 50s

Comment: Ok. So your model is not overfitting. Rather it is underfitting. You mentioned you have tuned the learning rate. What values have you tried and how?

Comment: I've tried 0.005 up to 0.01

Comment: Is this the [UCI wine dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/wine+quality) which you are using?

Comment: Yes this is it.

Comment: Then it has imbalanced classes and you must account for it to be able to get higher accuracy. Run `print(df['quality'].value_counts())` to see what I mean. Further, the number of classes is 11 (score from 0 to 10) not 9, although class 0, 1, 2 and 10 does not exist in the samples. And make sure you pass `num_classes` argument to `to_categoriacl()` function. Finally, you may need to increase model capacity (i.e. number of layers or number of units in a layer) to have a stronger model and therefore resolve the underfitting problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you are using real test data for validation, which is not OK! Validation data set is part of the training data.

I would suggest you use:

```
validation_split = 0.1
```

to use 10% of training data for validation purposes.

One of the options is that your network is overfitting. Try adding Dropout layers, this might help. Further, have you tried non-scaled data with outliers?

Further, the number of epochs seems too high. Try 5 or 10 epochs for such simple data set for starters. Similarly, the batch size could be further experimented with.

Comment: The validation accuracy is still in the 50s. Doesn't overfitting mean it would be way higher than training accuracy? I will try your suggestions though

Comment: I've added comment regarding your validation setting.

Comment: It seems MLPs do really bad with this dataset. I tried with RandomForest and it worked way better

Comment: To verify this claim, you can try: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neural_networks_supervised.html, the sklearn's perceptron. I still think this is a matter of tweaking.